# QooxDoo FrontEnd + Python BackEnd ( SimpleXMLRPCServer) problems

Tags: python, rpc, qooxdoo, simplexmlrpcserver

I have tried Qooxdoo and I made a simple Python server with SimpleXMLRPCServer, with a Python test I get the data without problems, but can I get this data from Qooxdoo? I get lost, and I've searched for 3 days but didn't get solutions.

I try this:

```
var JSON_lista_empresas = 1000
button1.addListener("execute", function(e) 
{
    var rpc = new qx.io.remote.Rpc();
    rpc.setServiceName("get_data");
    //rpc.setCrossDomain(true);
    rpc.setUrl("http://192.168.1.54:46000");
    rpc.addListener("completed", function(event)
    {
        console.log(event.getData());
    });
    rpc.callAsync( JSON_lista_empresas, '');
});
```

And I tried other options but got nothing :(

The link to files:

http://mieresdelcamin.es/owncloud/public.php?service=files&dir=%2Fjesus%2Ffiles%2FQooxdoo

I tried and read all of qooxdoo-contrib.

---

Well,

RpcPython --> Ok

and in class/qooxdoo -> test.py

run server [start-server.py] and query from webroser:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000//?_ScriptTransport_id=1&nocache=1366909868006&_ScriptTransport_data={%22service%22%3A%22qooxdoo.test%22%2C%22method%22%3A%22echo%22%2C%22id%22%3A1%2C%22params%22%3A[%22Por%20fin%22]}
```

and the reply in webroser is:

qx.io.remote.ScriptTransport._requestFinished(1,{"error": null, "id": 1, "result": "Client said: [ Por fin ]"});

but if i query from qooxdoo like the reply is [error.png]

The code for qooxdoo:

```
var rpc = new qx.io.remote.Rpc( "http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
    rpc.setCrossDomain( true);
    rpc.setServiceName( 'qooxdoo.test');
// asynchronous call
    var handler = function(result, exc) {
        if (exc == null) {
            alert("Result of async call: " + result);
        } else {
            alert("Exception during async call: " + exc+ result);
        }
    };
rpc.callAsync(handler, "echo", "Por fin");
```

I lost :((

Files in:

http://mieresdelcamin.es/owncloud/public.php?service=files&dir=%2Fjesus%2Ffiles%2FQooxdoo

Well, with Firebug this error in owncloud qx.io.remote.ScriptTransport.....is detect

¿?.............

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you confuse XML-RPC with JSON-RPC and qooxdoo only supports the latter. These protocols are similar but the data interchange format is different (XML or JSON). Instead of the `SimpleXMLRPCServer` you could use "RpcPython" on the server side which is a qooxdoo contrib project.

See:

- http://qooxdoo.org/contrib/project/rpcpython
- http://sourceforge.net/p/qooxdoo-contrib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/qooxdoo-contrib/RpcPython/

Once you have this server up and running you should be able to test it:

- http://manual.qooxdoo.org/2.1.1/pages/communication/rpc_server_writer_guide.html#testing-a-new-server
- http://sourceforge.net/p/qooxdoo-contrib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/qooxdoo-contrib/RpcPython/trunk/services/class/qooxdoo/test.py

After that your qooxdoo (client) code hopefully works also. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

In the file http.py of qxjsonrc module in the line 66 change

```
response='qx.io.remote.ScriptTransport._requestFinished(%s,%s);'%(scriptTransportID,response)
```

for

```
response='qx.io.remote.transport.Script._requestFinished(%s,%s);'%(scriptTransportID,response)
```

And run fine :))

This link for package modified:

http://mieresdelcamin.es/owncloud/public.php?service=files&dir=%2Fjesus%2Ffiles%2FQooxdoo

Best Regards and thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

As Richard already pointed Qooxdoo only supports its flavor of JSON-RPC.

I maintain a fork of original *rpcpython* called [QooxdooCherrypyJsonRpc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/QooxdooCherrypyJsonRpc). The main goal was to hand over transport  protocol to some robust framework, and leave only JSON RPC stuff. CherryPy, obviously a robust framework, allows HTTP, WSGI and FastCGI deployment. Code was refactored and covered with tests. Later I added upload/download support and consistent timezone datetime interchange.

At very minimum your Python backend may look like (call it test.py):

```
import cherrypy
import qxcpjsonrpc as rpc

class Test(rpc.Service):

  @rpc.public
  def add(self, x, y):
    return x + y

config = {
  '/service' : {
    'tools.jsonrpc.on' : True
  },
  '/resource' : {
    'tools.staticdir.on'  : True,
    'tools.staticdir.dir' : '/path/to/your/built/qooxdoo/app'
  }
}
cherrypy.tools.jsonrpc = rpc.ServerTool()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(config = config)
```

Then you can do in your qooxdoo code as follows:

```
var rpc = new qx.io.remote.Rpc();
rpc.setServiceName('test.Test');
rpc.setUrl('http://127.0.0.1:8080/service');
rpc.setCrossDomain(true); // you need this for opening app from file://
rpc.addListener("completed", function(event)
{
  console.log(event.getData());
});
rpc.callAsyncListeners(this, 'add', 5, 7);
```

Or open the link directly:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/service?_ScriptTransport_id=1&_ScriptTransport_data=%7B%22params%22%3A+%5B12%2C+13%5D%2C+%22id%22%3A+1%2C+%22service%22%3A+%22test.Test%22%2C+%22method%22%3A+%22add%22%7D
```

For more info take a look at the package page I posted above.

Answer (score -1):

Richard Sternagel wrote about rpcpython. This version of rpcpython doesn't work with present version of simplejson. Becouse in json.py have incorrect import:

```
    from simplejson.decoder import ANYTHING
    from simplejson.scanner import Scanner, pattern
```

Improve rpcpython or use another server, for example CherryPy.